# How do i install an OS onto an SSD

Tags: windows-10, ssd

First off I'm pretty new here. Feel free to correct me with anything or ask me for more information.

So I bought an SSD and I'm not sure what to do with it. My goal is to hook it up to my laptop or desktop and having an SSD plugged in instead of an HDD. I'm really not too tech savy, especially with hardware. Do I need to install an operating system first? I was thinking of getting windows 10 pro for it. I need it anyways because I want to run Docker, but I'm desktop only has Windows home edition.

TL;DR
I bought an SSD and some cables. How do I get it up and running quickly (on the software side). I feel like someone who knows how to build a PC could help me here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not asking for recommendations for obtaining software. You just need to connect the SSD and install windows to it then change your bios settings to allow booting from external devices.

Answer (score 1):

You have a Window home but you need Window pro, then things are easy: just replce the HDD with the SSD and install Win 10 pro.

If you wanted to keep the existing Windows you had first to clone the HDD and then replace the HDD with the SSD.